can not locate ros-jazzy on debian bookworm
I see here http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu/conf/distributions that jazzy exist in bookworm.
I update my source with deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg] http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu  bookworm main
without any error.
But any "jazzy" package does exist.
What did i miss ?

The answer is maybe here : https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2000.html#jazzy-jalisco-may-2024-may-2029. I have to compile from sources

If that is the solution, then you should post it as an answer.
